# How do I use twiml.gather continuously in existing call?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I want to be able to capture both parties speech to text continuously in a call and send those strings off to be translated in real-time and then use twiml.say to speak the text back. I have not been having much luck with this and wondering how I should go about doing this.

The one user will make a call from their phone to the other support person which is at a web browser.  I have the call setup and working fine, however I cannot find any documentation anywhere that is aligned with what I am wanting to do and wondering if it is possible or if I need to be looking down a different route.

Should anyone have any advice or has seen samples similar to this I would love to see them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's not currently possible to capture a two legged conversation with `<Gather>` and speech recognition. So you might need to look somewhere else for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks philnash! Can you think of doing this anyway using a conference room and translation boots as agents? Just curious.  Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by "translation boots (bots?)" ?

Comment: Sorry...so I was asked to put together a pic where we can have two people speaking different languages in a support call and have each sides spoken language translated for the other.  We currently have a Google cloud service that will take a full sentence and perform transliteration on it.  So what I was wondering is if another approach might be to have a conference room with two people speaking different languages and then two bots or let's say websockets or services that are in the conference as well. One bot would translate from Spanish to English let's say and the other English to Spanish.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to mimick something like Skypes translation but just for voice and between a phone and web browser via twilio.

Comment: You can't really get the realtime stream of audio from a conference easily. The only way to do it would be to make a SIP connection from your server to Twilio and then dial that into the conference, and read the audio from the stream. But I don't have any more detail than that. We did once demo a live transcription from a conference, but the feature hasn't surfaced yet, you might get more details by contacting [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about that.

Comment: Thanks again! Will check it out. Just knowing the other piece regarding gather can't be done saved me a bit of time. Enjoy the holidays!

Comment: Unsure how it is done....going to research now, but just in case anyone else needs a little direction for research, this might hold the key. Real-time transcription of audio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am74WU1zENA

Comment: Hey Phil can you please help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157444/real-time-transcription-twilio-agent-conference)